# Design Issue: Handling Customer Portal with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have existing microservices for my webapp. But I want to build a customer portal (separate website and angular frontend) which will access some of my APIs in the webapp. Registration is already handled, whilst other pages will only have View + List.

Which is a cleaner and better approach for handling the the View + List APIs:

1. Create a PortalResource Controller (/customerportal) to handle all API calls from the customer portal
2. Use existing webapp's Controllers and just add a different mapping (may involve adding 5-10 mappings to 2-4 different controllers)

Also, in my webapp, these view + list pages already exists. But in Customer Portal, several columns are hidden and some are added. Would it be better to:

1. Create a separate API to handle different columns response, or
2. Reuse webapp's API, then just add a flag `customerPortal` when necessary

If it matters, technology used is Java, Spring Boot.

Comment: It would be difficult to answer without visualizing the system architecture that you currently have. Could you add a visualization of the existing architecture?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit hard to answer the question without information about what the application does or how the architecture sits.
Nevertheless, I will point out a few things.

1. Context mapping - It's important to map out the context in your backend application. Let's say your backend application is doing several things e.g. users and bank accounts. In this case, we need to modularize our application into different modules/services (or at least different controllers).
2. Ubiquitous language - You need to identify the common language for your domain. Ubiquitous Language in DDD act likes an integrity check for our model. For instance, if you want to create APIs for fetching user(s) or customer(s), then the word "portal" shouldn't be in your domain. This is because in the case that another consumer wants to consume same endpoint(s) or your portal stops consuming the endpoints, your domain will have the word "portal" which don't have any meaning in your context/application.

I would recommend you create new APIs if you are exposing new endpoints/data and use the existing one if you are exposing the same data.